# How to limit filescanner to only import certain characters?

Tags: java, string

I want to read in words from a word list, but only words that contain characters of the alphabet, so no special characters like é, ï, -, etc

this is what I've got so far:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("wordlist.txt").getFile());
try (Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(file)) {
    while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
        String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
        if (line.length() == 5) {          
            list.add(line);
        }
    }
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    System.out.println("The file doesn't exists!");
}
```

Comment: `line.length() == 5` has nothing to do with your condition and is obviously not what you want. Replace it by something that reflects your condition.

Comment: Side note: avoid declaring lists as specific implementations like `ArrayList`, instead use `List`.  This allows you to not be tied to a specific implementation and use the interface as intended.  e.g.: `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Can you share an example of the input file? Does it have one word per line, or do you need to split the line?

Comment: @Henry it does, it limits the max character length to 5, which is what I want. I didn't add it to the question because I've already done that.

Comment: @Mureinik It's one word per line only, no seperated values. But it has words with special characters which I don't want.

Comment: @Walt "it limits the max character length to 5": actually, no. It requires the word has exactly 5 characters.

Comment: Is there a special reason to use classloader/getRessource? I succeded with `try (Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File ("namen")))` - does classloader load files from an jar?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to check both the string contents and its length in one shot:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-z]{1,5}$");
try (Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(file)) {
    while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
        String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
        if (Pattern.matcher(line).matches()) {          
            list.add(line);
        }
    }
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    System.out.println("The file doesn't exists!");
}
```

Comment: The `^` and `$` are not necessary in the pattern (but also don't hurt) as `matches` will match the full input against the pattern.

Comment: @Henry true 'dat. I usually like to add them to make it seems more explicit, but I guess we could lose them.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a second condition:

```
if (line.length() == 5 && line.matches ("[A-Z][a-z]*")) {
```

cat namen

```
Müler
J. F. Kennedy
Janis Joplin
Mirii
Renée
```

list

```
Mirii
```